# Bulma - Tiles not breaking onto the next line

Tags: css, bulma

I'm trying to create multiline tiles for a pintrest type layout. The problem I'm having is the tiles are placed horizontally and go off the page. I need them to wrap onto the next line. I can't seem to find anything in [the docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/tiles/):

Here's my code (copied from the docs). The items will be pragmatically inserted.

```
<div class="tile is-ancestor">
    <div class="tile is-parent">
      <div class="tile is-child card is-6">
        <p class="title">One</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tile is-child card is-6">
        <p class="title">Two</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tile is-child card is-6">
        <p class="title">Three</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tile is-child card is-6">
        <p class="title">Four</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried `is-multiline` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you remove is-6? It is making each tiles to be on the same line.

Comment: Also, can you explain a little more on what is the end result that you are seeking?

Comment: please show solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your issue is that you are assigning `is-6` for 4 elements resulting to the total of 24 columns while the doc says that it is a 12 column grid. So, it is overflowing.

I don't think Tile is the solution as it is using flex and what you want is to be able to control the overflow.

Solution:

1. Simply create a `div` and show your 'tiles' as a list with `display: inline-block`. Give it a width and height you want. It will automatically push the 'tiles' to another line.
2. Remove `is-6` which will all n number of your tiles to display in that same line.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. I ended up using the `masonry-layout`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I didn't really want to control columns width with `is-..`. Just wanted content to wrap so I did this:

```
<div class="tile is-ancestor is-flex-wrap-wrap">
```